# Explicit example of drift $F$ so that the law of $F+B$ is not absolutely continuous with respect to $B$

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Let $\mu_0$ be the law of Brownian motion on the space of continuous functions. If $\mu\sim\mu_0$ agrees on null sets then there is some progressively measurable $F\in W_0^{1,2}$ a.s. so that $\mu$ is the law of $F+B$. Conversely, if $F$ satisfies Novikov or Kazamaki or some other condition (which is stronger than just being a.s. $W_0^{1,2}$) then the law of $F+B$ is equivalent to that of $B$.

> What is an explicit example of a drift $F$ that is progressively measurable, almost surely in $W_0^{1,2}$ but so that the law of $F+B$ is not equivalent to that of $B$?